# Changing SECONDARY Monitor screen resolution in c#

Tags: c#, winapi, pinvoke

I need to change secondary monitor screen resolution dynamically.

I found the following resource which calls Win API. The problem is, it only set the primary monitor. I believe I have to change the dmDeviceName, but I am not sure how to pass it.

http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/2a631d72-206d-4036-a3f2-2e150f297515

```
dm.dmDeviceName //what is the input to this?
dm.dmPelsWidth = width; 
dm.dmPelsHeight = height; 
int iRet = User_32.ChangeDisplaySettings(ref dm, User_32.CDS_TEST);
```

Comment: From the MSDN documentation for `DEVMODE`: *"A zero-terminated character array that specifies the "friendly" name of the printer or display; for example, "PCL/HP LaserJet" in the case of PCL/HP LaserJet. This string is unique among device drivers. Note that this name may be truncated to fit in the dmDeviceName array."*, see: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183565.aspx

Comment: Use EnumDisplayDevices()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try this ...not exactly but will helps you...

use [EnumDisplayDevices](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533226%28VS.85%29.aspx) to figure out what displays you have available and [EnumDisplaySettings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533265.aspx) to get a list of available resolutions for your displays. Use [ChangeDisplaySettings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533260.aspx) to set the resolution you need.

Comment: I would use ChangeDisplaySettingsEx as it takes a device name as a parameter, the device name would be something like \\.\DisplayX see https://github.com/chilversc/utilities/blob/master/Mon/Mon/Mon.cpp for a C example that attaches a monitor, setting its resolution and position.

Comment: Thanks, the source code is good I am using EnumDisplayDevices and ChangeDisplaySettingsEx. I got my job done.